# How to find all files with a particular parent directory in linux?

Tags: linux

How do you find all files with a particular parent directory in the linux command terminal?

I know to find all files using `find` like so:

```
find . -name filename.extension
```

But is it possible to find all `filename.extension` files with the parent directory of `foldername`?

I have tried the following but this does not work:

```
find . -name foldername/filename.extension
```

And I cannot find any example of how to do this.

So some example results I would expect are as so:

```
./example/project/website/foldername/filename.extension
./folder/demo/foldername/filename.extension
./more/files/foldername/filename.extension
./business/assets/foldername/filename.extension
./steven/foldername/filename.extension
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: `locate filename.extension | grep foldername/!#:1`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `-path` switch with [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

```
find . -path \*/foldername/filename.extension
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try this

```
locate "/*/foldername/filename.extension"
```

provided you have updated index with `updatedb`

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

```
find ./ | grep 'foldername/filename.extension$'
```

"find" command will find all files, and "grep" will filter them by regular expression.

PS.
Also you can use "-exec" parameter of "find".

Answer (score 1):

Answering the more generic question, I was hoping this would work

```
find . -path '*/foldername/*'
```

But instead of **all files with parent** it gives **all files with ancestor**. This will show only children:

```
find . -path '*/foldername/*' | sed 's|.*foldername/\([^/]*\).*|\1|' | sort -u
```

or

```
find . | egrep -o 'foldername/[^/]*' | sed 's|[^/]*/||' | sort -u
```

But that doesn't give paths, so

```
find . -iname foldername -exec find {} -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 \;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find all directories named `examples`.
2. Then omit the results who has any parent directory named `node_modules`.

**`find . -type d -name examples | grep -v node_modules`**

Answer (score 0):

If you use fd (https://github.com/sharkdp/fd):

```
fd -p foldername/filename.extension .
```

Answer (score -3):

Just show results in the parentdirectory

`Find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'file.extension'`

Comment: No, this will not find the file in all sub folders with one command.

Comment: this will just print out the parent with context, consider you're looking for a file that exists in multiple directories, this will just show all of them and in no way refines the search.